# Relacionamento com laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando criar um relacionamento com as tabelas do meu banco de dados usando laravel, mas com uma certa dificuldade na lógica.

Tenho as tabelas; `content`, `client` e `user`

Um `user` pode ter diversos `client` e um `client` pode ter diversos `user`, para isso criei o relacionamento `ManyToMany`. (tabela `client_user` com os campos `user_id` e `client_id`), até aí tudo bem, consegui fazer o relacionamento normalmente e agora consigo saber quais clientes pertemcem a qual usuario.

Só que eu preciso agora, selecionar os `contents` do `client` que percentem a este `user`, como eu faria isso?

Pensei em criar uma tabela pivô (também) para `content` e `client` mas como eu faria essa seleção?

Quero pegar os `contents` que pertencem ao `client` que percente ao `user`...

Vejam o [exemplo do banco de dados](http://www.laravelsd.com/share/VaLaVD)

Comment: Você faz uso do Eloquent ORM do laravel? Tem o relacionamento dos modelos criados?

Comment: Vi que tem mais uma tabela ManyToMany no ralacionamento entre cliente e content. Um client pode ter vários contents?

Comment: @LucasTonon sim.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido ter uma tabela pivô no relacionamento entre client e content, pois cada content só pode ser de um client, então content carrega a chave de client. Sobre a questão do acesso aos dados relacionados, você já tentou usar o relacionamento **hasManyThrough**? veja na documentação do Laravel um exemplo: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through